# Recommended TeX editor for Mac

Tags: editors, mac

I just purchased a Mac and I am trying to decide which TeX editor to use.  The security preferences did not recognize TeXStudio or Texmaker which are the two I am most familiar with.  Do you think it is safe to override the security and download either of those or does someone have a recommended application that is recognized by OSX?  Any suggestions or recommendations welcomed.

Comment: Sublime Text is a good option with the LaTeXTools plugin.

Comment: It is not even close to being a duplicate.  Maybe you posted the wrong link.

Comment: the problem is, I guess that your title bears no relation to your question. Hence, @JosephWright took your question to be about which Tex Editor to choose for your Mac. As to your question, if you are attempting to download TeXStudio or Texmaker from the usual Website then 'unknown' just means they likely haven't registered with Apple and not that they are incompatible with OSX. You might also consider TeXShop

Comment: You have also asked two questions in one, and the second part is definitely close to the duplicate question.

Comment: The OSX security system gives some reassurance that someone at Apple has allowed an app into the App Store, but that's about it.  You might get more reassurance by picking an editor that is widely used by 1000s of others on OSX without problems - and for that see the linked duplicate answer.

Comment: One OSX only option that is not in the linked answer but that you might like is Peter Borg's Smultron editor which you could find in the app store (not that I'm endorsing it - personally I use macvim).

Answer (score 0):

For as long as I have been using LaTeX I have used TeXStudio. Regardless of whether I was working on OSX or Linux. Another option I would suggest is the TeXlipse addon for Eclipse, which is not as quick to set up though.